# is it possible to replace existing react native app with a new one?

Tags: react-native, migration, react-native-bridge

I have a react native project on **0. 59** version and I tried to do major updates to **0. 60**. But it seems to be impossible I can not run the app on the emulator. So I had this idea of creating an empty project and to transfer my code on it. Has someone ever done something like this?

- Is there a way to link existing app on the app store with a new

Comment: As long as the bundle identifier and signing certificates are the same, there would be no problem to create a new project and transfer code

Comment: let's try this if it works i will let you know

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can start a complete new app and replace it in the App Store with the new one.

The app is only identified by the bundle identifier (iOS) or the applicationId (android).

But I would recommend using [upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) before migrating to a new project.